# Python: IF statement and multiple OR

Tags: python, python-3.x

Being new to Python, I have this pseudo code on my mind:

```
if vars 1-4 are passed and all of them are 1:
    if it’s var1 or 2:
        print("a")
    if it’s var3
        print("b")
    if it’s var4
        print("c")

if vars 1-4 are passed and all of them are either 2, 3 or 4:
    if it’s var1 or 2:
        print("d")
    if it’s var3:
        print("e") and so on

if vars 1-4 are passed and all of them are either 0 or 5-10:
    if it’s var1 or 2:
        print("f") and so forth
```

I have tried a few approaches, but am yet to manage it. For instance:

```
if arg in [var1, var2, var3, var4] and [var1, var2, var3, var4] == 1:
    if var in [var1, var2]:
        print("a")
    if var == var3:
        print("b")
    if var == var4:
        print("c")

if arg in [var1, var2, var3, var4] and 2 <= [var1, var2, var3, var4] <= 4:
    if var in [var1, var2]:
        print("d") #and so on

if arg in [var1, var2, var3, var4] and 5 <= [var1, var2, var3, var4] <= 10: #+ put the 0
    if var in [var1, var2]:
        print("f") #and so forth
```

The part with `if test in [var1, var2, var3, var4]` works fine with using all 4 variables, but not so with checking if they are equal to 1. Furthermore, the second part, with the range (and third with range + 0) is even worse.
I could probably split all of these and test them individually with an OR in front of each and everyone of them, but that’s impossible in the long run with more variables. Surely, there must be some more Pythonic way?

**For clarification on usage:**
Code is used inside a function which takes one argument (1 of 4 variables at a time), depending on which (var1-4) different printouts should be made. Variables are entered by the user, stored outside the function and can be in the range of 0-10, independently of each other.

Comment: A `list` will never be equal to an `int` unless you tweak them beyond recognition. You really need to check out the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/index.html).

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with this code?

Comment: What is `test`? What does "if they're passed" mean? What does "If it's var1" mean? What exactly are you trying to do here?

Comment: Your clarification doesn't help. Where are these four variables coming from? If all four of them are `1`, `test` will be equal to *all* of them so "if it's var1 or var2" makes no sense (or at least, `b` or `c` will never ever get printed). Try writing some actual code first and then come back with a specific question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I'm not sure I get this right, but it sounds to me like you are creating four variables (lets name them `a` to `d`) and pass one of them to a function (`foo(x)`) with a single argument `x`. Then you are trying to check inside `foo(x)`, which of `a, b, c, d` has been passed as the `x` parameter of `foo(x)`. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, and then there are checks for values of the vars, depending of which different printouts are made.

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing an integer with a list which will always result False.

I guess you are trying to check if all the values in a list equals to 1. You can do it like that:

```
all(item == 1 for item in items)
```

You can also do it:

```
if var1==var2==var3==var4==1:
print "ok"
```

Comment: Aye, except there is no real list outside actually, just the 4 variables. As i _could_ check at the same if any of the 4 vars matched the argument passed to the function (`if arg in [var1, var2, var3, var4]`), i thought that the same could be done for checking if any of them contained a certain int (`[var1, var2, var3, var4] == 1`). Sadly, not that simple.

Comment: @poccapx actually even in the first portion , you are creating a list and then comparing if a particular element exists or not in that list, so it works. But in the second potion you are forming a list but comparing whole of it with an int, which isn't valid. If you don't afford a list, then you can simply do  if var1 ==1 and var2==1 and var3==1 and var4==1.

Comment: I see. Is there a shorter way, except for list, without writing == 1 four times? Considering there could be even more vars.

Comment: I don't think so. Why don't you create a list with all your variables first or at least a tuple and then use it while comparison? Isn't it obvious?

Comment: Just 10 days into Python :)  I'll try that. Thank you!

Comment: @Poccapx,  i didn't knew it works, i just tried and it works. You can see it :)